# A-frame: onclick function conflict?

Tags: function, aframe, conflict

I'm working in a scene with several assets that brings text on screen when clicked. I used for this a component called "texto-html". Then I added an introduction screen with a start button, with its own js file ("boton-intro.js"). After I added this, the first assets stop working. Could it be a conflict between onclick functions?

This is the link to the project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/48b5ad79-1824-4fe6-a8c3-151c52c108fc
(It is all in Spanish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an unclosed `<script>` tag where the `texto-html` component was defined

```
<script>
<script>
// somewhere near line 12 of index.html
AFRAME.registerComponent('texto-html', 
...
)
</script>
```

When the file was parsed, the compiler threw an error

> Unexpected token <

when it got to the second script tag. Once removed, you can press the buttons, and different `div`s pop up.